# Antialiasing on CAShapeLayers

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, antialiasing

I have a custom view for a loading indicator which is comprised of a number of `CAShapeLayers` which I perform various animations on to represent various states. In the init method I create a number of shape layers and add them as sublayers to the view's layer. The issue I'm having is the shapes that I'm drawing have very rough edges and don't seem to be antialiased. I've tried a number of things from similar answers on here but I can't seem to antialias the shapes. I've never had this problem before then drawing directly in `drawRect`.

Is there anything I'm missing or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Update: Here's a comparison of how the shapes are being drawn:

[image: Comparison of drawing methods]

On the left I'm drawing in `layoutSubviews` using this code:

```
CGFloat lineWidth = 2.5f;
CGFloat radius = (self.bounds.size.width - lineWidth)/2;
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame)/2, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)/2);

CGFloat startAngle = - ((float)M_PI / 2);
CGFloat endAngle = (2 * (float)M_PI) + startAngle;

UIBezierPath *trackPath =  [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center
                                                          radius:radius
                                                      startAngle:startAngle
                                                        endAngle:endAngle
                                                       clockwise:YES];
self.trackLayer.path = trackPath.CGPath;
self.trackLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth;
```

On the right I'm calling a separate method from `awakeFromNib`:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    ....
    self.trackLayer = [self trackShape]
    [self.layer addSublayer:self.trackLayer];
}

-(CAShapeLayer*)trackShape
{
    float start_angle = 2*M_PI*-M_PI_2;
    float end_angle = 2*M_PI*1-M_PI_2;
    float minSize = MIN(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    float radius = (minSize-_strokeWidth)/2 -4;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,self.frame.size.height/2);
    CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center
                                                 radius:radius
                                             startAngle:start_angle
                                               endAngle:end_angle
                                              clockwise:YES].CGPath;
    circle.strokeColor = self.trackColor.CGColor;
    circle.fillColor = nil;
    circle.lineWidth = (_strokeWidth == -1.0) ? minSize * _strokeWidthRatio
    : _strokeWidth;
    circle.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    return circle;
}
```

Comment: The `CAShapeLayer` docs say, "The shape will be drawn antialiased, and whenever possible it will be mapped into screen space before being rasterized to preserve resolution independence. However, certain kinds of image processing operations, such as CoreImage filters, applied to the layer or its ancestors may force rasterization in a local coordinate space." Whenever I just add a `CAShapeLayer`, it's always anti-aliased, so perhaps you can share what you're doing (code, screen snapshot, etc.), so we can figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Rob I've updated with a screenshot and code.

Comment: Both circles are actually anti-aliased. The one on the right looks jaggier than the one on the right, but it's really hard to tell because they're different sizes. Can you draw these precisely the same size (and share what the resulting `radius` and `lineWidth` values you used)? With circles, slight changes (e.g. 38 vs 38.3) in the `radius` can radically alter the visual effect of the anti-aliasing, so make sure the `radius` values are exactly the same.

Comment: BTW, I find that the rendering via Core Graphics calls in `drawRect` can render superior results (smoother, better antialiasing, etc.) than the `CAShapeLayer` technique. Also, if you use the `CAShapeLayer` technique, I find that a shadow with a small radius (e.g. 0.5), and an `shadowOffset` of `CGSizeZero` can soften the curve just enough to make it look a lot smoother.

Answer (score 2):

The picture you provided is exactly what happened to me. I got the chunky circle. In my case, the code was inside the drawRect method. The problem was that I was adding a CAShapeLayer, as a subLayer of my view, every time drawRect was called.

So to anyone who stumbles upon something similar, keep track of the CAShapeLayer you are adding or clear everything before drawing again in the drawRect.

Comment: This was my issue. Removing the superimposed CAShapeLayers resulted in the edges not becoming jagged with each subsequent redraw. Thanks Micho.